# isolation forest algorithm in python

Tags: python, r, algorithm, random-forest

I am trying to reproduce the algorithm described in the Isolation Forest paper in python. http://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf?q=isolation

This is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn as sk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA


def _h(i):
    return np.log(i) + 0.5772156649 


def _c(n):
    if n > 2:
        h = _h(n-1)
        return 2*h - 2*(n - 1)/n
    if n == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def _anomaly_score(dict_scores, n_samples):
    score = np.array([np.mean(dict_scores[k]) for k in dict_scores.keys()])
    score = -score/_c(n_samples)

    return 2**score


def _split_data(X):
    ''' split the data in the left and right nodes ''' 
    n_samples, n_columns = X.shape
    n_features = n_columns - 1

    feature_id = np.random.randint(low=0, high=n_features-1)
    feature = X[:, feature_id]
    split_value = np.random.choice(feature)
    left_X = X[feature <= split_value]
    right_X = X[feature > split_value]
    return left_X, right_X, feature_id, split_value


def iTree(X, add_index=False, max_depth = np.inf):            
    ''' construct an isolation tree and returns the number of step required
    to isolate an element. A column of index is added to the input matrix X if  
    add_index=True. This column is required in the algorithm. ''' 

    n_split = {} 
    def iterate(X, count = 0):

        n_samples, n_columns = X.shape
        n_features = n_columns - 1

        if count > max_depth:
            for index in X[:,-1]:
                n_split[index] = count
            return

        if n_samples == 1:
            index = X[0, n_columns-1]
            n_split[index] = count
            return 
        else:
            lX, rX, feature_id, split_value = _split_data(X)
            # Uncomment the print to visualize a draft of 
            # the construction of the tree
            #print(lX[:,-1], rX[:,-1], feature_id, split_value, n_split)
            n_samples_lX, _ = lX.shape
            n_samples_rX, _ = rX.shape
            if n_samples_lX > 0:
                iterate(lX, count+1)
            if n_samples_rX >0:
                iterate(rX, count+1)

    if add_index:
        n_samples, _ = X.shape
        X = np.c_[X, range(n_samples)]

    iterate(X)
    return n_split


class iForest():
    ''' Class to construct the isolation forest.

    -n_estimators: is the number of trees in the forest,

    -sample_size: is the bootstrap parameter used during the construction
    of the forest,

    -add_index: adds a column of index to the matrix X. This is required and 
    add_index can be set to False only if the last column of X contains 
    already indeces.

    -max_depth: is the maximum depth of each tree
    '''
    def __init__(self, n_estimators=20, sample_size=None, add_index = True, 
                 max_depth = 100):
        self.n_estimators = n_estimators
        self.sample_size = sample_size
        self.add_index = add_index
        self.max_depth = max_depth
        return 

    def fit(self, X):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape
        if self.sample_size == None:
            self.sample_size = int(n_samples/2)

        if self.add_index:
            X = np.c_[X, range(n_samples)]


        trees = [iTree(X[np.random.choice(n_samples, 
                                          self.sample_size, 
                                          replace=False)],
                       max_depth=self.max_depth) 
                 for i in range(self.n_estimators)]

        self.all_anomaly_score_ = {k:None for k in range(n_samples)}
        for k in self.all_anomaly_score_.keys():
            self.all_anomaly_score_[k] = np.array([tree[k] 
                                                   for tree in trees 
                                                   if k in tree])

        self.anomaly_score_ = _anomaly_score(self.all_anomaly_score_, n_samples)
        return self
```

The main part of the code is the iTree function that returns a dictionary with the number of steps required to isolate each sample.

A column of index is attached to the input matrix `X` in order to make easier to understand what are the samples in each node.

When I compare the result obtained with my code and the ones obtained with the isolation forest available for R I get different results.

Consider for example that stackloss dataset :

```
data = pd.read_csv("stackloss.csv")
X = data.as_matrix()[:, 1:]

max_depth = 100
itree = iTree(X, add_index=True, max_depth=max_depth) #example of isolation tree 


iforest = iForest(n_estimators=1, max_depth=max_depth, sample_size=21) # isolation forest 
iforest.fit(X)

sol = np.argsort(iforest.anomaly_score_)
#correct sol = [10  5  4  8 12  9 11 17  6 19  7 14 13 15 18  3 20 16  2  1  0]
```

`sol` is often different by correct solution obtained with the R software.
https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/iforest/

The correct solution in R has been obtained with:

```
> tr = IsolationTrees(stackloss,ntree = 100000,hlim = 100, rFactor = 1)
> as = AnomalyScore(stackloss, tr)
> order(as$outF)
 [1] 11  6  5  9 13 10 12 18  7 20  8 15 14 16 19  4 21 17  3  2  1
> order(as$outF)-1
 [1] 10  5  4  8 12  9 11 17  6 19  7 14 13 15 18  3 20 16  2  1  0
>
```

Where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally been able to solve the problem. 
The code is still slow due to the continuous copy operation performed in each split on the data.

This is the working version of the algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn as sk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def _h(i):
    return np.log(i) + 0.5772156649 


def _c(n):
    if n > 2:
        h = _h(n-1)
        return 2*h - 2*(n - 1)/n
    if n == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def _anomaly_score(score, n_samples):

    score = -score/_c(n_samples)

    return 2**score


def _split_data(X):
    ''' split the data in the left and right nodes ''' 
    n_samples, n_columns = X.shape
    n_features = n_columns - 1
    m = M = 0
    while m == M:
        feature_id = np.random.randint(low=0, high=n_features)
        feature = X[:, feature_id]
        m = feature.min()
        M = feature.max()
        #print(m, M, feature_id, X.shape)

    split_value = np.random.uniform(m, M, 1)
    left_X = X[feature <= split_value]
    right_X = X[feature > split_value]
    return left_X, right_X, feature_id, split_value


def iTree(X, add_index=False, max_depth = np.inf):            
    ''' construct an isolation tree and returns the number of step required
    to isolate an element. A column of index is added to the input matrix X if  
    add_index=True. This column is required in the algorithm. ''' 

    n_split = {} 
    def iterate(X, count = 0):

        n_samples, n_columns = X.shape
        n_features = n_columns - 1

        if count > max_depth:
            for index in X[:,-1]:
                n_split[index] = count
            return

        if n_samples == 1:
            index = X[0, n_columns-1]
            n_split[index] = count
            return 
        else:
            lX, rX, feature_id, split_value = _split_data(X)
            # Uncomment the print to visualize a draft of 
            # the construction of the tree
            #print(lX[:,-1], rX[:,-1], feature_id, split_value, n_split)
            n_samples_lX, _ = lX.shape
            n_samples_rX, _ = rX.shape
            if n_samples_lX > 0:
                iterate(lX, count+1)
            if n_samples_rX >0:
                iterate(rX, count+1)

    if add_index:
        n_samples, _ = X.shape
        X = np.c_[X, range(n_samples)]

    iterate(X)
    return n_split


class iForest():
    ''' Class to construct the isolation forest.

    -n_estimators: is the number of trees in the forest,

    -sample_size: is the bootstrap parameter used during the construction
    of the forest,

    -add_index: adds a column of index to the matrix X. This is required and 
    add_index can be set to False only if the last column of X contains 
    already indeces.

    -max_depth: is the maximum depth of each tree
    '''
    def __init__(self, n_estimators=20, sample_size=None, add_index = True, 
                 max_depth = 100):
        self.n_estimators = n_estimators
        self.sample_size = sample_size
        self.add_index = add_index
        self.max_depth = max_depth
        return 

    def fit(self, X):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape
        if self.sample_size == None:
            self.sample_size = int(n_samples/2)

        if self.add_index:
            X = np.c_[X, range(n_samples)]


        trees = [iTree(X[np.random.choice(n_samples, 
                                          self.sample_size, 
                                          replace=False)],
                       max_depth=self.max_depth) 
                 for i in range(self.n_estimators)]

        self.path_length_ = {k:None for k in range(n_samples)}
        for k in self.path_length_.keys():
            self.path_length_[k] = np.array([tree[k] 
                                             for tree in trees 
                                             if k in tree])
        self.path_length_ = np.array([self.path_length_[k].mean() for k in 
                                      self.path_length_.keys()])
        self.anomaly_score_ = _anomaly_score(self.path_length_, self.sample_size)
        return self
```

Comment: What _was_ the problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
self.anomaly_score_ = _anomaly_score(self.all_anomaly_score_, n_samples)
```

You're calculating _anomaly_score with n_samples which is total number of samples. However, you are building trees with subsamples. Therefore, when you're calculating the average search length '_c(n)' you should use sample_size instead of n_samples as the trees are build with subsamples. So, I believe your code should be:

```
self.anomaly_score_ = _anomaly_score(self.all_anomaly_score_, self.sample_size)
```

Comment: Very good spot. This is a bug but I do not think that this is the cause of the problem. 21 is the total size of the data so in this case `n_samples=sample_size`

Comment: Are you saying that your solution is always 1 less than solution from R? or is your solution totally different? When I run your code multiple times the outputs are not the same (similarity in outputs increase with more trees due to random splits).

Comment: I think my solution is always different. This afternoon I will post the code for a simpler comparison with the R script.   I have reported the result - 1 in R to take into account the different index system in R and python

Answer (score 1):

There is a pull-request in scikit-learn: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4163

Comment: Thanks . This will be very useful. Now I am just curious to know what I am doing wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

Donbeo, your code works pretty well with just a few minor adjustments, the main problem it had is that you missed one of the base cases (end condition) of the recursive algorithm, so it hangs in loop when that condition comes up. You need something to this effect in the _split_data function (shown in code below) and also handle the this case in the iterate function (not shown)

```
minv = maxv = 0
inspected = Set()   # this set tracks the candidates that we already inspected
while minv == maxv:

    # check whether we run out of features to try an none of them has different values,
    # if that is the case we need to break the loop otherwise this loops forever
    if len(inspected) == n_features:
        # if we run out of features to try an none of them has different values,
        # return -1 to signal the caller that we can't split X anymore.
        return X, X, -1, None

    feature_id = np.random.randint(low=0, high=n_features)
    if feature_id not in inspected:
        inspected.add(feature_id)
        split_feature = X[:, feature_id]
        minv = split_feature.min()
        maxv = split_feature.max()
```